# How to set order of SQL-response?

Tags: sql-server, json, mule

I've got a mule flow that queries a SQL-server database and then converts the response to JSON and then writes the JSON comma separated to file.

My problem is that the order of the column in the written file doesn't match the order of the fields in the query. How tho define the order of columns in a query answer?

The JSON to CSV conversion is like this:

```
 public class Bean2CSV {

  /**
* @param args
* @throws JSONException 
*/
public String conv2csv(Object input) throws JSONException {
  if (!input.equals(null)){
   String inputstr = (String)input;

 JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(inputstr);
 String csv = CDL.toString(jsonArr);
 csv = csv.replace(',', ';');
 System.out.println(inputstr); //csv
 System.out.println(csv); //csv
 return csv;
  } else return "";}
}
```

and here is the flow

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"     
xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json"       
xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"     
xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"     
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"     
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jdbc"       
xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"      
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" version="CE-3.4.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-    
http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring- beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core     
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:cognos_import.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="dataSource" name="dataSource" class="org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource" destroy-method="shutdown">
        <spring:property name="driverName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <spring:property name="user" value="${dbusername}"/>
        <spring:property name="password" value="${dbpassword}"/>
    </spring:bean>
    <spring:bean id="changeDB" class="ChangeDatabase">
        <spring:property name="serverip" value="${dbserverip}"/>
        <spring:property name="serverport" value="${dbserverport}"/>
        <spring:property name="dbprefix" value="${dbprefix}"/>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
<jdbc:connector name="db_conn" dataSource-ref="dataSource" validateConnections="false" pollingFrequency="5000" doc:name="Database">
    <jdbc:query key="readbal" value="SELECT #[header:INBOUND:company] as company, AcNo as Konto , R2 as Avd, #[header:INBOUND:period] as Period,  sum(AcAm) as Saldo FROM AcTr WHERE (AcYrPr &lt;= #[header:INBOUND:period]) and (AcNo &lt; 3000) GROUP BY AcNo,R2 ORDER BY AcNo,R2;"/>
    <jdbc:query key="readres" value="SELECT #[header:INBOUND:company] as company, AcNo as Konto , R2 as Avd, #[header:INBOUND:period] as Period,  sum(AcAm) as Saldo FROM AcTr WHERE (AcYrPr &lt;= #[header:INBOUND:period]) and (AcYrPr &gt;= #[header:INBOUND:starttid])  and (AcNo &gt;= 3000) GROUP BY AcNo,R2 ORDER BY AcNo,R2"/>
    <jdbc:query key="readiclr" value="SELECT #[header:INBOUND:company] as company, AcTr.AcNo as Konto , AcTr.R2 as Avd, #[header:INBOUND:period] as Period,  sum(AcTr.AcAm) as Saldo,sum(AcTr.CurAm) as ValutaBel, AcTr.Cur as Valuta, AcTr.R1 as FtgID FROM AcTr LEFT JOIN Actor ON AcTr.R1=Actor.R1 WHERE (AcTr.AcYrPr &lt;= #[header:INBOUND:period]) and (AcTr.AcYrPr &gt;= #[header:INBOUND:starttid]) and Actor.SAcSet=2 and (AcTr.AcNo=3019 or AcTr.AcNo=3099 or AcTr.AcNo=3199 or AcTr.AcNo=3299 or AcTr.AcNo=3499 or AcTr.AcNo=3519 or AcTr.AcNo=3599 or AcTr.AcNo=3699 or AcTr.AcNo=3799 or AcTr.AcNo=3919 or AcTr.AcNo=3999 or AcTr.AcNo=4299 or AcTr.AcNo=4399 or AcTr.AcNo=4599 or AcTr.AcNo=4699 or AcTr.AcNo=4799 or AcTr.AcNo=5099 or AcTr.AcNo=5299 or AcTr.AcNo=5499 or AcTr.AcNo=5699 or AcTr.AcNo=5799 or AcTr.AcNo=5999 or AcTr.AcNo=6099 or AcTr.AcNo=6399 or AcTr.AcNo=6499 or AcTr.AcNo=6999 or AcTr.AcNo=7999 or AcTr.AcNo=8399 or AcTr.AcNo=8499) and AcTr.Sup&lt;&gt;0 GROUP BY AcTr.AcNo,AcTr.R2,AcTr.R1,AcTr.Cur"/>
    <jdbc:query key="readickr" value="SELECT #[header:INBOUND:company] as company, AcTr.AcNo as Konto , AcTr.R2 as Avd, #[header:INBOUND:period] as Period,  sum(AcTr.AcAm) as Saldo,sum(AcTr.CurAm) as ValutaBel, AcTr.Cur as Valuta, AcTr.R1 as FtgID FROM AcTr LEFT JOIN Actor ON AcTr.R1=Actor.R1 WHERE (AcTr.AcYrPr &lt;= #[header:INBOUND:period]) and (AcTr.AcYrPr &gt;= #[header:INBOUND:starttid]) and Actor.CAcSet=2 and (AcTr.AcNo=3019 or AcTr.AcNo=3099 or AcTr.AcNo=3199 or AcTr.AcNo=3299 or AcTr.AcNo=3499 or AcTr.AcNo=3519 or AcTr.AcNo=3599 or AcTr.AcNo=3699 or AcTr.AcNo=3799 or AcTr.AcNo=3919 or AcTr.AcNo=3999 or AcTr.AcNo=4299 or AcTr.AcNo=4399 or AcTr.AcNo=4599 or AcTr.AcNo=4699 or AcTr.AcNo=4799 or AcTr.AcNo=5099 or AcTr.AcNo=5299 or AcTr.AcNo=5499 or AcTr.AcNo=5699 or AcTr.AcNo=5799 or AcTr.AcNo=5999 or AcTr.AcNo=6099 or AcTr.AcNo=6399 or AcTr.AcNo=6499 or AcTr.AcNo=6999 or AcTr.AcNo=7999 or AcTr.AcNo=8399 or AcTr.AcNo=8499) and AcTr.Cust&lt;&gt;0 GROUP BY AcTr.AcNo,AcTr.R2,AcTr.R1,AcTr.Cur"/>
    <jdbc:query key="readiclb" value="SELECT #[header:INBOUND:company] as company, AcTr.AcNo as Konto, AcTr.R2 as Avd, #[header:INBOUND:period] as Period,  sum(AcTr.AcAm) as Saldo, sum(AcTr.CurAm) as ValutaBel, AcTr.Cur as Valuta, AcTr.R1 as FtgID FROM AcTr LEFT JOIN Actor ON AcTr.R1=Actor.R1 WHERE (AcTr.AcYrPr &lt;= #[header:INBOUND:period]) and Actor.SAcSet=2 and AcTr.Sup&lt;&gt;0 and (AcTr.AcNo=1511 or AcTr.AcNo=2441) GROUP BY AcTr.AcNo,AcTr.R2,AcTr.R1,AcTr.Cur"/>
    <jdbc:query key="readickb" value="SELECT #[header:INBOUND:company] as company, AcTr.AcNo as Konto, AcTr.R2 as Avd, #[header:INBOUND:period] as Period,  sum(AcTr.AcAm) as Saldo, sum(AcTr.CurAm) as ValutaBel, AcTr.Cur as Valuta, AcTr.R1 as FtgID FROM AcTr LEFT JOIN Actor ON AcTr.R1=Actor.R1 WHERE (AcTr.AcYrPr &lt;= #[header:INBOUND:period]) and Actor.CAcSet=2 and AcTr.Cust&lt;&gt;0 and (AcTr.AcNo=1511 or AcTr.AcNo=2441) GROUP BY AcTr.AcNo,AcTr.R2,AcTr.R1,AcTr.Cur"/>
</jdbc:connector>
<file:connector name="output" outputPattern=" #[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy-hh-mm-ss]#[header:INBOUND:company].txt" autoDelete="false" outputAppend="true" streaming="false" validateConnections="false" doc:name="File"/>
<message-properties-transformer name="delete-content-type-header" doc:name="Message Properties">
    <delete-message-property key="Content-type"/>
</message-properties-transformer>
<message-properties-transformer name="add-csv-content-type-header" doc:name="Message Properties">
    <add-message-property key="Content-Type" value="text/csv"/>
</message-properties-transformer>
<message-properties-transformer name="add-filename" doc:name="Message Properties">
    <add-message-property key="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=testfil.txt"/>
</message-properties-transformer>
<flow name="CD-test1Flow1" doc:name="CD-test1Flow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <not-filter doc:name="Not">
        <wildcard-filter pattern="*favicon*" caseSensitive="true"/>
    </not-filter>
    <logger message="Log1 #[message.getPayload()]! " level="INFO" doc:name="Logger1"/>
    <http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer doc:name="Body to Parameter Map"/>
    <component class="ValidationService3x" doc:name="Java"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    <set-variable variableName="Filename" value=" #[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy-hh-mm-ss]-#[header:INBOUND:company]-#[header:INBOUND:period]" doc:name="FilenameVar"/>
    <component doc:name="Java">
        <spring-object bean="changeDB"/>
    </component>
    <all doc:name="All">
        <processor-chain>
            <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="readbal" connector-ref="db_conn" doc:name="DB"/>
            <expression-filter expression="payload.size() &gt; 0" doc:name="not empty"/>
            <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
            <component class="Bean2CSV" doc:name="Java"/>
            <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
            <file:outbound-endpoint path="${outputfolder}" outputPattern="#[flowVars['Filename']]-bal.csv" connector-ref="output" doc:name="File"/>
        </processor-chain>
        <processor-chain>
            <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="readres" connector-ref="db_conn" doc:name="DB100-ickr"/>
            <expression-filter expression="payload.size() &gt; 0" doc:name="not empty"/>
            <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
            <component class="Bean2CSV" doc:name="Java"/>
            <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
            <file:outbound-endpoint path="${outputfolder}" outputPattern="#[flowVars['Filename']]-res.csv" connector-ref="output" doc:name="File"/>
        </processor-chain>
        <processor-chain>
            <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="readiclb" connector-ref="db_conn" doc:name="DB100-ickr"/>
            <expression-filter expression="payload.size() &gt; 0" doc:name="not empty"/>
            <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
            <component class="Bean2CSV" doc:name="Java"/>
            <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
            <file:outbound-endpoint path="${outputfolder}" outputPattern="#[flowVars['Filename']]-icb.csv" connector-ref="output" doc:name="File"/>
        </processor-chain>
        <processor-chain>
            <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="readickb" connector-ref="db_conn" doc:name="DB100-ickr"/>
            <expression-filter expression="payload.size() &gt; 0" doc:name="not empty"/>
            <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
            <component class="Bean2CSVnotfirstline" doc:name="Java"/>
            <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
            <file:outbound-endpoint path="${outputfolder}" outputPattern="#[flowVars['Filename']]-icb.csv" connector-ref="output" doc:name="File"/>
        </processor-chain>
        <processor-chain>
            <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="readiclr" connector-ref="db_conn" doc:name="DB100-ickr"/>
            <expression-filter expression="payload.size() &gt; 0" doc:name="not empty"/>
            <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
            <component class="Bean2CSV" doc:name="Java"/>
            <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
            <file:outbound-endpoint path="${outputfolder}" outputPattern="#[flowVars['Filename']]-icr.csv" connector-ref="output" doc:name="File"/>
        </processor-chain>
        <processor-chain>
            <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="readickr" connector-ref="db_conn" doc:name="DB100-ickr"/>
            <expression-filter expression="payload.size() &gt; 0" doc:name="not empty"/>
            <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
            <component class="Bean2CSVnotfirstline" doc:name="Java"/>
            <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
            <file:outbound-endpoint path="${outputfolder}" outputPattern="#[flowVars['Filename']]-icr.csv" connector-ref="output" doc:name="File"/>
        </processor-chain>
    </all>
    <set-payload value="Nu är 100 tankat till #[flowVars['Filename']] " doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <http:response-builder doc:name="HTTP Response Builder"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Can you share your flow?

Comment: I've now added the Mule flow in the post above!

Comment: Is there a reason why you've chosen to use a Java component over DataMapper? I would assume you're working with CE...

Comment: Hi, yes that's correct I use CE edt and Datamapper is only in EE.

Comment: When I run the query in DatabaseSpy I get the order of the query in the answer but not when the query is running through the mule engine.

Comment: I've now found that it's the JDBC-endpoint that delivers the wrong order. Can I configure the JDBC-endpoint to preserve the order of the query in the answer?

Comment: Could you possibly include the response you are getting from the JDBC query?